# If I have a wsp that is "Globally Deployed" in Central Admin > Manage farm solutions, where will it show up in my sites?

Tags: solution-package, central-administration

I figured it would show up under `Galleries > Solutions` or `Site Collection Administration > Site Collection features` in the site settings but I'm not seeing it in either of those locations.  Should I be looking in a different location?

Answer (score 4):

Solutions are deployed globally, if they doesn't contain any WebApplication-specific elements. Basically, this means that the solution doesn't affect `web.config`.

Solutions Gallery is only for sandboxed solutions. You will never find anything from farm solutions in this gallery.

A farm solution not obligatory contains Site Collection Features. Instead, it may contain Site Feature, or Web Application Feature, or Farm Feature. Also, it may contain no features at all: for example, this is true for solutions which have only SharePoint mapped folders.

To determine elements which includes your particular solution, you should navigate to it's wsp file, rename it to *.cab, open, and then inspect manifest.xml file.

Comment: once in the cab, you can also check out the feature.xml (if it's there) and read the scope, that'll tell you where it's at.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your features are hidden then you cant see it on the Site administration. if it is deployed as wsp you can find it out at solutions Galleries under central Admin.